# Counterfactual modeling where variable is present in treatment but not control group?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, missing-data, difference-in-difference, case-control-study

I'm working with patient-level healthcare data in a pre vs. post difference-in-differences analysis where the goal is to estimate the average treatment effect for nursing care.

Patients in the treatment group received home visits from a nurse while patients in the control group *did not* receive visits.

Given that: 1) nurses often treated multiple patients, 2) outcomes of interest are correlated within nurse ID, and 3) coding fixed effects for each Nurse ID would overfit, a random intercept linked to the Nurse ID for each patient seems appropriate.

One problem: **How should a random effect be coded for patients in the control group, who received no nursing care? Should all control patients receive the same proxy "nurse ID"?**